# How to handle singe-row subquery returns more than one row error with case statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am building an Oracle query which has a case statement involved.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 
    ((SELECT agent_or_group_id from trans_slot where slot_id = 
    (SELECT slot_id from trans_slot where slot_alias = 'PP' and measure_expiration > sysdate)) > 0) 
/*The below subquery returns 1 row*/
  THEN (SELECT agent_or_group_id from trans_slot where slot_id = 
    (SELECT slot_id from trans_slot where slot_alias = 'PP' and measure_expiration > sysdate))
  ELSE 
/* The below subquery returns 2 rows*/
   (SELECT child_agent_id FROM agent_object_group_member WHERE parent_agent_id IN
    (SELECT agent_or_group_id FROM trans_slot WHERE slot_id IN
     (SELECT slot_id FROM trans_slot WHERE slot_alias = 'PP' AND measure_expiration > sysdate)
     )
    ) 
END
 "Agent_ID" from DUAL;
```

When the run the subqueries independent they run fine. But running the whole query returns

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, you can't do it like that. You'll need to use a left outer join and then chose the column value you want to display.

Here's a simplified example based on the SQL you provided:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 0 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 10 child_id, 0 parent_id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 20 child_id, 0 parent_id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 30 child_id, 1 parent_id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 40 child_id, 2 parent_id FROM dual)
---- end of mimicking two tables with the sample data in them. See the query below:
SELECT COALESCE(t2.child_id, t1.id) ID
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.parent_id AND t1.id = 0);

        ID
----------
        10
        20
         2
         1
```

Here, I have used the t1 and t2 subqueries to mimic the output you'd get from your main subqueries in your original query.

Then we outer join t2 to t1 only where the t1.id = 0. By doing this, you can then simply choose the t2.child_id value if it exists, otherwise use the t1.id value.

(I realise that in your example, the t1 equivalent subquery would only generate 1 row, based on what you said, but I've included 3 rows so that you can see what the results would be based on the different ids.)

---

ETA:

In your case, the t1 subquery in my example above would be:

```
SELECT agent_or_group_id
from   trans_slot
where  slot_id = (SELECT slot_id
                  from   trans_slot
                  where  slot_alias = 'PP'
                  and    measure_expiration > sysdate)
```

and the t2 subquery would be:

```
SELECT child_agent_id
FROM   agent_object_group_member
WHERE  parent_agent_id IN (SELECT agent_or_group_id
                           FROM trans_slot
                           WHERE slot_id IN (SELECT slot_id
                                             FROM   trans_slot
                                             WHERE slot_alias = 'PP'
                                             AND measure_expiration > sysdate))
```

Comment: can we get to chat directly? i didn't understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: Sorry, I can't access chat. I've updated my answer with what you would use to define the t1 and t2 subqueries.